# Is this usage of await/async correct?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm new to async/await and I want to make sure that this way of doing it is correct:

```
public async Task DoHeavyWorkAsync() 
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        getResponseFromFarawaySlowServerAndDoSomethingWithIt();
    });
}

public async void ConsumeAsync()
{
    Task longRunningTask = DoHeavyWorkAsync();
    // do a lot of other stuffs here that does not depend on DoHeavyWorkAsync()
    await longRunningTask;
}
```

Is this way of using async/await correct or did I do something wrong?

Comment: why event start it until you need it?

Comment: This code wont compile, you're missing the `async` keyword in `ConsumeAsync`

Comment: Is this a desktop or a web application?

Comment: this is a desktop application

Comment: No. it is not correct

Comment: If you are able to make `getResponseFromFarawaySlowServerAndDoSomethingWithIt` async, do it, instead of wrapping it with `Task.Run`.

Comment: By making `ConsumeAsync` return `void`, you won't be able to effectively await that method. It will be considered fire-and-forget.

Comment: You should use `public async Task ConsumeAsync` instead of `public async void ConsumeAsync`

Comment: @DanielA.White - it makes sense to start long operation early so it may complete by the time you are done with other slow things. I suspect that it is actually the main part of the question - whether it is ok to start operation early and `await` much later (if it is the question - yes).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov We have no idea what he's asking, because he didn't say what, specifically, he was concerned about.  If he wants to know if it's okay to do work while an asynchronous operation is running he should have asked that.

Comment: @Servy Yes... I thought " I suspect ..." would be enough to make it clear that it is just my guess, but possibly not. It was really answer to Daniel's comment about why one would do that at all....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. In `DoHeavyWorkAsync`, you don't really need to generate a state machine using `await Task.Run`, you can simply `return Task.Run`:

   ```
   public Task DoHeavyWorkAsync() 
   {
      return Task.Run(() => getResponseFromFarawaySlowServerAndDoSomethingWithIt());
   }
   ```
2. `async void` is ment solely for **async Event Handlers**. If your async method is `void` returning, it should return a `Task` instead:

   ```
   public async Task ConsumeAsync()
   ```
3. If `DoHeavyWorkAsync` is an IO based operation, there is no need to wrap it inside a `Task.Run` as it is inherently asynchronous. Simply using `await` will do. More-so, you shouldn't do [*async over sync*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). Instead, you should make the caller of the synchronous method explicitly use `Task.Run`, if needed at all:

   ```
   public void DoHeavyWork()
   {
       getResponseFromFarawaySlowServerAndDoSomethingWithIt();  
   }
   ```

   and then explicitly wrap it in the calling method:

   ```
   Task.Run(DoHeavyWork);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

from API designer point of view, **I would consider spliting method** `getResponseFromFarawaySlowServerAndDoSomethingWithIt` to:
 `getResponseFromFarawaySlowServer` and `doSomething()`.
Then you can wrap only the long running method with async wrapper

usage would then:

```
var response = await getResponseFromFarawaySlowServerAsync();
doSomething(response);
```

another thing that smells a little bit: `getResponseFromFarawaySlowServer` itself is not async. the http call or webservice call itself should be awaited inside that method if possible. Currently you are creating new thread thad does nothing just wait. This is  be redundant if you awaited the http call instead

so instead

```
string getResponseFromFarawaySlowServer(){
  string response = new WebClient().DownloadString(uri);
  ...
  return response
}

async Task<string> getResponseFromFarawaySlowServerAsync(){ Task.StartNew..
```

you would directly:

```
async Task<string> getResponseFromFarawaySlowServerAsync(){
  string response = await new WebClient().DownloadStringAsync(uri);
  ...
  return response;
}
```